# Hide div and show it when target

Tags: css

I have this in my html:

```
<div>
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li id="h1">
      <a href="#h1">Home</a>
      <div>
        text here
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="h2">
      <a href="#h2">Services</a>
      <div>
        text here
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do is make the list items inline, while hiding their contents. And the contents would only be visible when I press the list item link. This is what I've tried so far on the css:

```
li {
  display: inline;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}

li:target {
  display: block;
}
```

However, this doest not work. The display: block; is not overriding the display: none;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, `li div` is more specific than `li:target`.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li:target` only refers to the `li` element itself that is targeted. Setting that li’s `display` property to `block` will not affect the containing `div` which `display` property is set to `none`. In fact, it will only overwrite the `display: inline` that’s defined on `li`.

When you want to display the `div` that’s inside the targeted `li` element, then you need to adjust the selector to actually match that div. For example using `li:target div` to match the specificity of the original rule:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}

li:target div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li id="h1">
      <a href="#h1">Home</a>
      <div>
        text here
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="h2">
      <a href="#h2">Services</a>
      <div>
        text here 2
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```